# NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays. Mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            NSMutableArray *miniArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++)
            {   
                [miniArray addObject:@"0"];
            }
            [array addObject:miniArray];
        }
```

Then, when I try to do this:

```
 [[array objectAtIndex:packIndex]replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"1"];
```

it crashes with: `[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Why ? How to fix ? Thanks !

**UPD**: 
I save this array in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[defaults setObject:array forKey:@"mainArray"];
```

Then, I read it in the other class:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mainArray"]];
```

Also, I must to mention that sometimes the code runs well and it changes "0" to "1". But it also crashes sometimes. So I cant see the logic, why it works fine or why it crashes sometimes.

Comment: What is boolArray? Did you mean miniArray?

Comment: @rdelmar yes, sorry. I ll fix it now.

Comment: Was that a typo in your question, or do you have that typo in your code?

Comment: @rdelmar typo in the question. In the code its correct.

Comment: This code should work fine. There's something you're not showing here. What's "packIndex"? What code happens between the block you're showing and the replace method?

Comment: Where do you define `packIndex`?  Can you show ALL the code in between what you have there and the line crashes?

Comment: I tested the above code, substituting numbers for packIndex and index, and it worked fine.

Comment: Again, what happens between the sniplet that you are showing and the line where the exception is trown?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that when you read the array out of NSUserDefaults, the mini-arrays are not automatically NSMutableArrays.

Try this:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mainArray"]];
for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    NSArray * tempArray = array[i];
    array[i] = [tempArray mutableCopy];
}
```

Edit:
Best Coder's answer explains why this is. 
Objects stored in NSUserDefaults are stored as immutable versions, basically NSUserDefaults is a plist and there is no flag marking an array as mutable/immutable so when you read them back out, they are assumed to be immutable.

Comment: I tried it and...it works GREAT! Thank you. Could you explain please, why the mini-arrays are not automatically NSMutaleArrays, if originally they are ?

Comment: @SmartTree All data read from `NSUserDefaults` comes back in its immutable form. Even the main array is immutable when read from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Just to add a little bit more info: NSUserDefaults always returns immutable collections, but for the general case of property lists, NSPropertyListSerialization has the option of returning mutable collections. So if you store the array somewhere other than NSUserDefaults, that's an option.

Comment: thank you, saved my time. also now i learned new thing about mutable array's :)

Answer (score 6):

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a
> mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string
> as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve
> using stringForKey: will be immutable.

Instead, make a mutableCopy of the array you retrieve from NSUserDefaults, add your object, then set your new array back in.

see this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults

Answer (score -5):

Try using more verbose code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [array objectAtIndex:packIndex];
[tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"1"];
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would help? The two are equivalent.

Comment: For some reason the mini arrays are not being stored as mutable arrays. This would force them to be mutable.

Comment: This will not force them to be mutable. You've probably worked in a language where assigning an object of one type to a variable of another type will cast the object. It doesn't work that way in Objective-C. All object variables are pointers, and assigning a pointer of one type to a pointer variable of another type will not change the underlying data — it just lies to the compiler about what the variable points to. Object types are just used for static type checking and making sure that properties uses the correct accessors.